# Close info window of a marker programmatically google maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, marker, infowindow, google-maps-sdk-ios

I know it's easy in the java version of Google Maps but I can't figure out how to get the info window to close in the objective C version of the SDK.

I'm using this method:

```
-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker {

    sharedGlobal.shouldShowPlayer = YES;

    /* adds the path to the map by decoding google's encoded string */
    [self addPath: sharedGlobal.encodedPathString];
}
```

And want to add a line to close the infowindow associated with marker.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```
mapView.selectedMarker = nil;
```

The comments on the `selectedMarker` property in GMSMapView.h say this:

```
/**
 * The marker that is selected.  Setting this property selects a particular
 * marker, showing an info window on it.  If this property is non-nil, setting
 * it to nil deselects the marker, hiding the info window.  This property is
 * observable using KVO.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<GMSMarker> selectedMarker;
```

Comment: very well answered...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT**

```
mapView.selectedMarker?.title = nil
```