# Wrong value for marker text passed to custom view

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-asynctask, android-location

I am developing an android application which displays a map. When it loads, it displays some addresses and sets markers for them.

When I click on any marker it should display a value in a custom view. But the custom text which is received from a json parser, gets a null value. When I click on the marker again, it sets correct value.

When I click on second marker it display 1st marker value. When I click on 2nd marker again it displays correct value. This process continues

Here's my code:

```
    private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{
        private Context mainContxt;
        Geocoder geocoder;
        public GeocoderTask(Context con){
        mainContxt=con;

        } 

        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
             Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mainContxt);
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0],1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return addresses;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) { 

       for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){             

                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        address.getCountryName());

                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(addressText);
                if(i==0)    {
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(14),2000,null);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
                }
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            }
       googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker_address) {
                    location=marker_address.getTitle();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new LoadSingleProperty().execute();
                //new LoadImage().execute();
                return false;

            }
        });

        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                View myContentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.custom_marker, null);
                tempnew_price=getPrice(temptotal_price+"" +email);
                TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentView
                        .findViewById(R.id.title));
               // tvTitle.setText(location);
                tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentView
                        .findViewById(R.id.snippet));

               ivProperty = ((ImageView) myContentView
                        .findViewById(R.id.image_property));

               tvTitle.setText(tempcovered_area+ " "+tempnew_price+System.getProperty("line.separator")+templocation);

               tvSnippet.setText("A "+ tempbedroom + " "+tempproperty_type);


              // new LoadImage().execute();
            ivProperty.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
                    return myContentView;


            }
        });
        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        search_property_activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Email", email);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

this is my loadsingle class coding.....

```
    class LoadSingleProperty extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivityMap.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Location. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            if(location!=null && !location.equals("")){
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Location", location));
                json= jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_loc_address, "GET", params);
            }
            Log.d("MyLocation: ", json.toString());

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    address = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ALL_ADDRESS);
                    //for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = address.getJSONObject(0);
                        templocation = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                        tempcovered_area=c.getString(TAG_COVERED_AREA);
                        temptotal_price=c.getString(TAG_Total_Price);

                        tempbedroom=c.getString(TAG_BEDROOM);
                        tempproperty_type=c.getString(TAG_PROPERTY_TYPE);
                        tempemail=c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        //} 
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }



    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();  
        new GeocoderTask(MainActivityMap.this).execute(location);
        }


    }
```

Help me friends ...thx in advance

Comment: if anyone have answer then help me????

Comment: if i call new GeocoderTask(MainActivityMap.this).execute(location); from loadsinglepropery on background ...nothing is changed

Comment: hi .....my suggestion is ..
see what value you are getting in 'locatiion'...? i think some thing went wrong here?

Comment: @gvsharma this is my json response when i clicked 1st time     04-01 12:39:10.469: D/MyLocation:(2534): {"address_all":[{"email_id":"asddd@a.bn","location":"Bokaro Steel City, Jharkhand, India","covered_area":"100sq-m","sell_type":"SELL","property_type":"House","total_price":"789","bedroom":"3BHK"}],"success":1}
that time all the field of custom view is null

Comment: Check if marker's info window is getting displayed before your json parsing is done

Comment: yeh @random that is right ..but how to solve it

Comment: you're trying to set title tvTitle with a class level variable  tempcovered_area inside infowindowadapter tvTitle.setText(tempcovered_area+ " "+tempnew_price+System.getProperty("line.separator")+templocation); You should not set the text until you get the value for tempcovered_area

Comment: but m getting value when i click 2nd time in marker @random

Comment: that's because the first time you click your marker, and the async task completes, it set the value for tempcovered_area. The second time you click it, this previous value is displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74245/discussion-between-tufan-and-random).

Comment: so @random how i can solve it acording to #gvsharma comment i had tried that too ..but nthnhg changed

Comment: hey @random now check my edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a constructor for LoadSingleProperty

```
class LoadSingleProperty extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Marker mMarker;

    public LoadSingleProperty(Marker marker){
      mMarker = marker;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

and pass your marker object to it.

```
new LoadSingleProperty(marker_address).execute();
```

Once parsing is done set your marker's title using [setTitle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setTitle%28java.lang.String%29) method for the marker

```
mMarker.setTitle(c.getString(TAG_PROPERTY_TYPE));
```

where you currently do this

```
tempproperty_type=c.getString(TAG_PROPERTY_TYPE);
```

Don't forget to refresh your info window once title is reset

[How to force refresh contents of the markerInfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342320/how-to-force-refresh-contents-of-the-markerinfowindow-in-google-maps-ios-sdk)

You may also want to show some sort of a loading icon till this time since you're performing a network request.

EDIT:

In case you're using a custom titleview, get a reference to InfoWindowAdapter object before setting as a adapter to googleMap

```
InfoWindowAdapter infoWindowAdapter = new InfoWindowAdapter() {...
```

Once parsing is complete, get info window view for mMarker object by calling

```
infoWindowAdapter.getInfoWindow(mMarker);
```

Find your textView from the view obtained above and set its text. Then refresh your info window by calling showInfoWindow() to update the info window.

Also please refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows).

> The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered
>   as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This
>   means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by
>   the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for
>   example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow()

Comment: hey @random but i have to use tem string bcz i want to set it on onother textview

Answer (score 0):

```
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {
    private Context mainContxt;
    Geocoder geocoder;

    public GeocoderTask(Context con) {
        mainContxt = con;

    }

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mainContxt);
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {

            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),
                    address.getLongitude());

            String addressText = String.format(
                    "%s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                            .getAddressLine(0) : "", address
                            .getCountryName());

            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(addressText);
            if (i == 0) {
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(14),
                        2000, null);
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newLatLng(latLng));
            }
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you write below code

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker_address) {
        location = marker_address.getTitle();
        new LoadSingleProperty().execute();

        return false;

    }
});
```

Take another customeWindowAdapter or else use the present one only and set that in onPostExecute() method of 'LoadSingleProperty' AsyncTask..
This will solve that.
ping here you have any queries